# Java program, Converting many spaces into tabs (\t)

Tags: java, string

For example I have the following data

```
  1007            0
  1008            0
  1009            0
```

In the above data I want to convert it to produce data like this

```
1007 (tab) 0
1008 (tab) 0
1009 (tab) 0
```

I have code like this, but the output is not as expected

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class SpaceToTab {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Masukkan data : ");
    String x = sc.nextLine().trim();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(x,"\n");

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
        String y = st.nextToken().replaceAll("\\s+","\t");
        System.out.println(y);
    }


}

}
```

and the above program produces the output
1007 (tab) 0

did not match my expectations

Comment: why do you use StringTokenizer? it's been deprecated for quite some versions of Java. have you debugged and checked whether you read the values you expected to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete StringTokenizer and move it to a loop:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Masukkan data : ");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
      String x = sc.nextLine().trim();
      x = x.replaceAll("\\s+", "\t");
      System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) { // Line without line ending.
    line = line.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", "\t");
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The InputStreamReader without extra charset parameter uses the platform default, the same as System.in.

Scanner does too much, tokenizing, line/token level.

The spaces in front (and at the end) are trimmed away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if (line!=null && line.contains("            ") {
        String[] split = line.split("            ");
        System.out.println(split[0] + " (tab) "+split[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class SpaceToTab {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Masukkan data : ");
    String x = sc.nextLine().trim();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(x," ");
    System.out.println(st.countTokens());

    String y = "";
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
        String i = st.nextToken();
        if(!i.trim().equals("0"))
        {
            y = y+i+ "\t";
        } else
        {
            y = y + i + " ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(y);
    sc.close();


}

}
```

Why not tokenize by space?